# How do I capture a CTRL-S without jQuery or any other library?

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I go about capturing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> event in a webpage?

I do not wish to use jQuery or any other special library.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're just using native / vanilla JavaScript, this should achieve the results you are after:

```
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 17) isCtrl=false;
}

document.onkeydown=function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 17) isCtrl=true;
    if(e.keyCode == 83 && isCtrl == true) {
        //run code for CTRL+S -- ie, save!
        return false;
    }
}
```

**What's happening?**

The **onkeydown** method checks to see if it is the CTRL key being pressed (key code **17**).
If so, we set the **isCtrl** value to **true** to mark it as being activated and in use. We can revert this value back to **false** within the **onkeyup** function.

We then look to see if any other keys are being pressed in conjunction with the ctrl key. In this example, key code **83** is for the S key. You can add your custom processing / data manipulation / save methods within this function, and we return **false** to try to stop the browser from acting on the CTRL-S key presses itself.

Comment: i dont think `e.which` is supported by some browsers (by some browsers we always mean IE)

Answer (score 45):

**An up to date answer in 2020.**

Since the Keyboard event object has been changed lately, and many of its old properties are now deprecated, here's a modernized code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 's') {
    // Prevent the Save dialog to open
    e.preventDefault();
    // Place your code here
    console.log('CTRL + S');
  }
});
```

Notice the new [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property, which contains the information about the stroked key. Additionally, some browsers might not allow code to override the system shortcuts.

Comment: It should also be noted that if you want to capture `CMD` + `S` for MacOS you should also check for `e.metaKey` which makes the whole check `if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.key === 's')`

Answer (score 9):

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 83) {
        alert('hello there');

        // your code here
        return false;
    }
};
```

You need to replace `document` with your actual input field.

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/obixav/2)

Comment: You need to set return false within the function to stop the browser from processing the save

Comment: `preventDefault` and `return false` are redundant.

Comment: I think this should be `document.onkeydown = [...]`

Comment: And `return false` should be inside the `if`

Answer (score 2):

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 83) {
        alert('strg+s');
    }
    return false;
};
```

Some events can't be captured, since they are capture by the system or application.

Comment: @AshwinSingh Unfortunately you are wrong dude. You just need to click into the result field and press strg+s. I don't mind if you upvote me for my working code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oops you wanted simultaneous, changed code to reflect your scenario

```
function iskeyPress(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
            if (e.ctrlKey&&e.keyCode == 83) {
               alert("Combination pressed");

               }
              return false;//To prevent default behaviour         
              }
```

Add this to body

```
  <body onkeyup="iskeypress()">
```

Comment: Without a return false, would the browser not also try to run the CTRL-S command?

Comment: Well that's the OP to decide, if he want's to prevent it or not.

Comment: True, but it would be good to mention it in your example to cover it.

Comment: Still won't work. You have to treat `strg` as modifier key like Blaster copied from my code.

Comment: `e.keyCode` can never be both `17` and `83` in the same condition check.

Comment: Still wrong, e.keyCode is either true or false but never 17, would you mind removing your downvote from my answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Add Shortcuts JS library and do the following code :

```
<script src="js/libs/shortcut/shortcut.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+S", function() {
            alert("لقد قمت بالصغط على مراقبة مع حرف السين");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mousetrap](https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap) is a great library to do this (8,000+ stars on Github).

**Documentation**: https://craig.is/killing/mice

```
// map multiple combinations to the same callback
Mousetrap.bind(['command+s', 'ctrl+s'], function() {
    console.log('command s or control s');

    // return false to prevent default browser behavior
    // and stop event from bubbling
    return false;
});
```