# Is there a way to create new key bindings for Microsoft Word add ins?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I have a basic Microsoft Word add in, but the target users for the application are power users who like to use the keyboard rather than the mouse for various things.

Is there a way to bind an action/button in the add-in to a key or a key combination? Instead of clicking a button, can an action be triggered by a key binding?

I want to attach something like:

`ctrl` + `l`

to something like this:

```
    function hightlightLongestWord() {
        Word.run(function (context) {
            // Queue a command to get the current selection and then
            // create a proxy range object with the results.
            var range = context.document.getSelection();

            
            // This variable will keep the search results for the longest word.
            var searchResults;
            
            // Queue a command to load the range selection result.
            context.load(range, 'text');
            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands
            // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    $("#template-description").text(range.text);
                    // Get the longest word from the selection.
                    var words = range.text.split(/\s+/);
                    var longestWord = words.reduce(function (word1, word2) { return word1.length > word2.length ? word1 : word2; });

                    // Queue a search command.
                    searchResults = range.search(longestWord, { matchCase: true, matchWholeWord: true });

                    // Queue a commmand to load the font property of the results.
                    context.load(searchResults, 'font');
                })
                .then(context.sync)
                .then(function () {
                    // Queue a command to highlight the search results.
                    searchResults.items[0].font.highlightColor = '#FF0000'; // Green
                    searchResults.items[0].font.bold = true;
                })
                .then(context.sync);
        })
        .catch(errorHandler);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer yes. But it's not the most practical. (this is the only way I know of doing something like this in add-ins)

You can make a javascript event handler to catch the combination of keypresses.

Here are some examples on that:
[How do I capture a CTRL-S without jQuery or any other library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362106/how-do-i-capture-a-ctrl-s-without-jquery-or-any-other-library)

This has a problem though that your add-in needs to be active to catch the keypress since the add-in is a website sideloaded to word. So if user is writing to Word and then hits ctrl+l, nothing happens if user does not click your add-in first.

Only way to override Words own key combinations, that I know of, is through VBA and macros (note that macros are not supported in office online): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsod/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in

You could however do something like Have a button in add-in: When clicking with ctrl down => do smth, when clicking normally => do something else, when clicking shift down => do some super formatting... etc...