# The AddEventListener Line doesn't work. What can I do?

Tags: javascript

I want to disable `CTRL + S` in the browser, so I can save my game, but it doesn't work.

The code looks like this right now:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.which == 83) { // ctrl + s
    event.preventDefault();
    saveGame();
  }
}, false);
```

The code for `saveGame()` is the following:

```js
function saveGame() {
  var gameSave = {
    score: score,
    clickingPower: clickingPower,
    costGoku: costGoku,
    gokus: gokus,
    costVerbalase: costVerbalase,
    verbalases: verbalases,
    costSkyview: costSkyview,
    skyviews: skyviews
  };
  localStorage.setItem("gameSave", JSON.stringify(gameSave));
}
```

The `saveGame()` function works perfectly fine, but I still wanted to provide it so you can see what it does for clarification. When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on my website it still wants to save the page and is not saving the game.

Comment: Have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery and here for vanilla JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362106/how-do-i-capture-a-ctrl-s-without-jquery-or-any-other-library

Comment: Is `saveGame` called when you click 'CTRL + S'?

Comment: Are you on a Mac or Windows machine ?

Comment: @1x2x3x4x Still doesn't work. Don't know why though.

Comment: @Dario I wanted to do that, yes but as I said it doesn't work.

Comment: @horcrux Sadly doesn't work either.

Comment: Weird, this needs more troubleshooting - I tried your code and it works fine. What environment are you testing in ? What browser ? Can you give more context around your code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the propagating, you can either do it with `event.stopPropagation();` or with `return false;`

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
            if (event.ctrlKey && event.which == 83) { // ctrl + s
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                saveGame();

        
            }
        }, false);
```

Or with return false;

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey && event.which == 83) { // ctrl + s
            event.preventDefault();
            saveGame();
            return false;
    
        }
    }, false);
```

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.which == 83) { // ctrl + s
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("saveGame()");


  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I literally just copied your code , into a plain html file, and it works just great.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>

      document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {

        console.log("keydown");
        console.log(event);

        if (event.ctrlKey && event.which == 83) { // ctrl + s
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("CTRL + S pressed !")
            saveGame()
        }

      }, true);

      function saveGame() {
        var gameSave = {
            score: 1,
            clickingPower: 2,
            costGoku: 3,
            gokus: 4,
            costVerbalase: 5,
            verbalases: 6,
            costSkyview: 7,
            skyviews: 8
        };
        localStorage.setItem("gameSave", JSON.stringify(gameSave));
        console.log("game saved !")
      }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I suggest doing the same on your end and see what happens. If it works here and not in the other project, you need to include more information, like what environment your in, how did you setup your project, what browser you are using, what OS and so on.